# Custom file type thumbnails or preview in Windows explorer

Tags: windows, geometry, preview, vector-graphics

I have *.geo vector geometry files (vector graphic file). This file format comes with Trumpf TruTOPS CAM application suite to handle laser cutting machines. *.geo file format contains geometry of single part and is internal for this suite. To create it one need convert AuotCAD *.dwg or *.dxf files.

I want to force this "GEO_Preview" app (which is associated with *.geo files to open preview in its window) to generate preview in windows explorer "preview side panel".

How to do that? So far i've read about some "registry hacks" and class id but don't understand a word. I'm asking you for step by step solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a lot more than a few registry entries if the application has not been written to be a preview handler nor any other type of thumbnail shell extension.

If you are unable to write your own viewer for this file-type you could try forcing this app to live as a child window inside a window you create. This is always going to be a bit of a hack but it might be a usable solution. **You** would have to implement the [preview handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144143(v=vs.85).aspx) part that hosts the real application...